# Bamboo - shared artifact not listed in deployment plan Artifact Download task list

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I have a build plan where I created a shared artifact. I ran the build plan and confirmed that the shared artifact was created by looking at the artifact tab in the build result.

However, I cannot find that artifact in the artifact list of my new Artifact Download task of my deployment project. Again, the artifact as defined in the build plan is shared.

Am I missing a step somewhere for sharing the artifact between the build plan and deployment project? the build plan has a single job (the default job).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be wrong:

- Make sure that the build plan being targeted by the deployment is the one with the artifact.  Sharing it is not enough.
- Double check that the artifact definition has the checkbox for shared checked.
- Select a completed build, select the build stage on the left, and select the artifacts tab.  You should see a bold section labeled "Shared artifacts can be found under:" followed by the path on disk to the artifact.  If this is not present then the problem is with how the artifact is being generated, not the deployment project.